# python tkinter issues running commands

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to run the function that switches the frame in the class LoginPage and the function buttonLoginClicked. It seems as though any functions I want to run from the CCTV **init** method only work in the LoginPage **init** method and I have no idea why. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from Login import *

TITLE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
NORMAL_FONT = ("Verdana", 8)

class CCTV(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="FittleworthLogo.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Fittleworth CCTV")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (LoginPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.labelTitle = ttk.Label(self, text="Login Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.labelUsername = ttk.Label(self, text="Username", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        self.entryUsername = ttk.Entry(self, font=NORMAL_FONT)
        self.labelPassword = ttk.Label(self, text="Password", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        self.entryPassword = ttk.Entry(self, show = "*", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        self.buttonLogin = ttk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.buttonLoginClicked)
        #self.buttonLogin = ttk.Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))

        self.labelTitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        self.labelUsername.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.entryUsername.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.labelPassword.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.entryPassword.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.buttonLogin.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=10)

    def buttonLoginClicked(self):
        global account
        username = self.entryUsername.get()
        password = self.entryPassword.get()

        validPassword = loggingIn(account, username, password)

        #This isn't working either
        self.buttonTest = ttk.Button(text="TEST", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        self.buttonTest.grid(row=4)

        if validPassword:
            #Need to switch frames to PageOne here
            #This doens't work
            controller.show_frame(PageOne)

            #This does
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Login successful", "You are now logged in")
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Login error", "Incorrect username or password")



class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.labelTitle = ttk.Label(self, text="Login Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.loginButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage))

        self.labelTitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        self.loginButton.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=10)


app = CCTV()
app.geometry("800x600")
account = gettingAccountInformation()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "only work in the LoginPage init method"? What happens when you move the code to where you want it? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error. More than likely, the error will tell you exactly what is wrong. If you don't get an error, how does the result differ from what you expect?

Comment: No I didn't get the error. I figured out why. It was because in the __init__ method, I needed to do     self.controller = controller in order to use it in the other functions. Then I would just use     self.controller.show_frame(PageOne) and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself with the following..

Add: self.controller = controller in the **init** method of each class

then to call it do: self.controller.show_frame(Page)

This worked for me anyway!